# number of text fields equal to number selected from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

http://jsfiddle.net/bbh2y4dL/5/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control mySelectBoxClass childage" name="noofchilds[]">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<a class="repeat">ADD MORE</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" class="add" style="display:none">Add Age</a>

<div id="light" class="white_content">
<div class="textboxDiv"></div><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>

</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
.black_overlay {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index:1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity:.80;
filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
padding: 16px;
border-radius:7px;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto;
}
.form-control {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 26px;
padding: 2px 0px 2px 12px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
color: #010F2B;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: #E6E8E9;
border: 2px solid #ebebeb;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out  0.15s;
transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
   }
```

javascript

```
$(function () {
$(".repeat").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.before($self.prev('table').clone());
});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".childage").change(function () {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $(".textboxDiv").html('');
    if (selVal > 0) {
        $(".add").css("display", "block");
        for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
            $(".textboxDiv").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" /><br>');
        }
    } else {
        $(".add").css("display", "none");
    }
});
});
```

I'm trying to create a popup which displays number of text field equal to number of value selected, its doing fine in this code but the problem is that i have to also duplicate the select box and then create the same functionality with all created selectbox...check my fiddle and suggest any solution

Comment: Please be more specific about what the problem is. Why can't you use the same approach for other `<select>`?

Comment: that means if you have 3 select boxes with each 3 selected means totally 9 text boxes you need? right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

HTML

```
<div class="repeatElement">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control mySelectBoxClass childage" name="noofchilds[]">
                <option selected>0</option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add" style="display:none">Add Age</a>
</div>

<a class="repeat">ADD MORE</a>

<div id="light" class="white_content">
    <div class="textboxDiv"></div><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="close">Close</a>

</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".repeat").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.before($self.prev('.repeatElement').clone());
    });

    $(document).on('change','.childage',function(){
       var selectVal = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
        if(selectVal > 0)
            $(this).closest('table').next('.add').show();
        else
            $(this).closest('table').next('.add').hide();
    });

    $(document).on('click','.add',function(){
        var selVal = $(this).prev().find('.childage').val();
        $(".textboxDiv").empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= selVal; i++) {
                $(".textboxDiv").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" /><br>');
        }
        $('#light').show();
        $('#fade').show();
    });

    $('#close').click(function(){
       $('#light').hide();
        $('#fade').hide();
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbh2y4dL/11/)**

Comment: thanks!!! that worked for me but  i  also want that each time div is duplicated "add more" option should be hidden and should be displayed only when i select value >0 from dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can use .live() , as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total=0;
    $(".childage").live('change', function () {
        var selVal = $(this).val();
        total=parseInt(total)+parseInt(selVal);
        $(".textboxDiv").html('');
        if (selVal > 0) {
            $(".add").css("display", "block");
            for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
                $(".textboxDiv").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" /><br>');
            }
        } else {
            $(".add").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```